# "Maximum call stack size exceeded" Calling function from inside the function

Tags: javascript, function, loops, if-statement

OK, so im trying to make a small sudoku generator, and i didn't get far before i met a problem. I meet the error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when the output in console.log is "a == b". Here is my code (Im not an experienced coder FUI)

```
function en_Til_Ni() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1;
} 

var enTilNi = en_Til_Ni(); 
console.log(enTilNi);

var a = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("a" + a);
var b = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("b" + b);
var c = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("c" + c);


console.log("---------------------------------------------");

function ikkeLike() { //this is where it goes wrong
    if (a != b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    }

    else if (a == b) { // It logs the numbers just fine, untill a == b
        ikkeLike();
    }

}

ikkeLike();
```

Comment: because when `a==b`, post that values of `a` and `b` doesn't change. hence the exit condition is never reached.

Comment: as an aside, recursion is relatively expensive for your use case; if the outcome is unknown until runtime you may wish to investigate using while.

Answer (score 1):

Of course you are getting this result, because you have no working exit condition.

You neeed to change the random values and check again until the wanted state is reached.

```js
function en_Til_Ni() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
}

function ikkeLike() {
    a = en_Til_Ni();
    b = en_Til_Ni();
    if (a !== b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    } else {              // no need for the opposite check
        ikkeLike();
    }
}

var a, b;                 // global variables
ikkeLike();
```

Better version without recursive call and a `do ... while` loop.

```js
function en_Til_Ni() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * 9) + 1;
}

function ikkeLike() {
    do {
        a = en_Til_Ni();
        b = en_Til_Ni();
    } while (a === b)
    console.log(a, b);
}

var a, b; // global variables
ikkeLike();
```

Comment: So i just have to make a new var inside the function?

Comment: you need to take new random values inside of the function, like code example 1. a better version is to use a loop structure without recursive calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is little hack for your problem :

Use setTimeout to avoid this error message , app see problem with infinity loops .

Also you need to make new values for a and b !

```js
function en_Til_Ni() {
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1;
} 

var enTilNi = en_Til_Ni(); 
console.log(enTilNi);

var a = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("a" + a);
var b = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("b" + b);
var c = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("c" + c);


console.log("---------------------------------------------");

function ikkeLike() { 

    if (a != b) {
        console.log(a, b);
    }

    else if (parseInt(a) == parseInt(b) ) { // It logs the numbers just fine, untill a == b
    
    console.log (" a == b  TRUE" ); 

    a = en_Til_Ni();
    b = en_Til_Ni();
    c = en_Til_Ni();

        setTimeout ( ikkeLike , 1 ) 
        console.log("cool")
        
    }

}

ikkeLike();
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that! What does the parseInt do tho?

Comment: No need for parse , it was just a check ! Main proble was when a==b after that they never get new values ... infinity loops makes red alert . You have button Run on code snippet !

Answer (score 0):

> OK, so im trying to make a small sudoku generator, and i didn't get
>   far before i met a problem.

Looks like you want to check if three values you have generated - `a`, `b` and `c` are not equal. And you want to keep generating the values of `b` and `c` till they are all different.

Change your method `en_Til_Ni` in such a way that it will keep generating random values till values are unique.

```
function en_Til_Ni() 
{
    var newValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*9)+1;
    args = [].slice.call(arguments);
    var isNotNew = args.some( function( item ){
       item == newValue;
    });

    return !isNotNew ? newValue : en_Til_Ni.apply( this, args ) ;
}
```

Now this method will always return unique values

```
var a = en_Til_Ni();
console.log("a" + a);
var b = en_Til_Ni(a);
console.log("b" + b);
var c = en_Til_Ni(a,b);
console.log("c" + c);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursion without the increment part. Let's look on ikkeLike() without the first condition:

```
function ikkeLike() {
  // We removed the first case for the simplicity
  if (a == b) {
    ikkeLike();
  }
}
```

Now you can easly see that in this case it is just an infinite loop...
You need to solve this case by changing 'a' or 'b' just before the recursive call:

```
function ikkeLike() {      
  if (a == b) {
    // <--Change 'a' or 'b' here before the recursive call to avoid infinite loop!
    ikkeLike();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This really helped me out.